# Plotting a line with list in an equation

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from math import *
f2 = open('C:\\Users\\Audrey\\Documents\\Regress1Par data.txt', 'r')
lines = f2.readlines()
f2.close()

x1 = []
y1 = []
z1 = []

for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    x1.append(float(p[0]))
    y1.append(float(p[1]))
    z1.append(float(p[2]))

plt.scatter(x1, y1)
yerr=z1
plt.errorbar(x1,y1,yerr=yerr, fmt='o')
plt.plot(2.53+9.33(x) for x in x1)
plt.show()
```

I get an error "type error: 'float' object is not callable"
How can I plot this line with x1 in it?

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your error, but `numpy.genfromtxt` could read that file much more simply. It could also catch any possible non-numeric entries in the data file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing an operator here:

```
plt.plot(2.53+9.33(x) for x in x1)
```

You need to use

```
plt.plot(2.53+9.33*(x) for x in x1)
```

because 9.33() is not a callable function:

```
 >>> 2.59+9.33(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    2.59+9.33(x)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: That probably fixed the initial problem but now its saying "float()

Comment: it saying    "float() argument must be string or a number"

Comment: You'll need to include the full traceback.  I have no idea what the new error is in reference to since you've changed your code.  My guess is that your data have a non-numeric value somewhere that cannot be converted to a float.